# Lost with LINQ and Expressions

Tags: linq

I'm trying to write a LINQ query on some objects where I need to only do a select if a filter value is set.

Is there a way to "change" the query dynamically to only do a select if this is set.

Comment: Your question is missing enough detail to be able to intelligently answer it.

Comment: Is this good ole LINQ to objects, or one of the fancy cousins LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities? That would make huge difference in writing an answer.

Comment: Could you give some more context?  Perhaps some code?

Comment: Don't look at "change"; rather, look at build-up via chaining composition and controlling the filters. The questions below show both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = Somthing().Where(x => x.IsSomethingYouAlwaysFilterBy);
if(FilterValueIsSet(filterValue))
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Property == filterValue)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `where` to find the items of interest, e.g.:

```
collection.Where(i => PassesFilter(i)).Select(i => i.InterestingValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but you can use predicate builder. [Predicate Builder example here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)